# Does the curl library execute javascript inside pages?

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I'm working with a few pages where javascript executes form submission on page load.

Does the curl library automatically execute javascript in web pages?  If it does, is there a way to return the changed DOM instead of the default one that I'm returning with simple curl code.

Here's my currentcode:

```
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $buffer = curl_exec_follow($curl_handle,10);        
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
```

Comment: cURL does not have a JavaScript parser, therefore can not execute it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it does not. It does not apply css styles either.

Answer (score 5):

[No](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/06/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_curl). A web page with embedded JavaScript is actually a program. CURL gives you the program's source code (HTML and JavaScript), but doesn't run that program.

To run a page's embedded JavaScript you need (1) a JavaScript interpreter, and (2) the Document Object Model (DOM) for the page.

Browsers have these, but **PHP does not**.

People are working on PHP versions of these, but developing these are big tasks.

If this is what you need, you might skip PHP and instead look at writing C++ code using WebKit.

Comment: A web page should not be described as a 'program'.

Answer (score 1):

PHP curl is NOT a full browser. It is just a library that is used for communicating with servers, using HTTP, FTP, et cetera. It does not do neither rendering nor parsing.